# Problems with button actions when trying to login to Website Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to login to a web application that I have using VBA.

However, I have a problem trying to click on the button, because the button is into a "div" and "span" tags and this does not have the "name" or "id" attribute.

How do I click on a button that is into these tags?(Please see the screenshot below)

[imagen_Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jabAq.png)

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Carla

Comment: could do something like get the element by id for the "password" then use nextSibling.nextSibling.firstchild(x4) ?

Comment: Hi,
Do you have any example using nextSibling where can I take a look?
Thanks in advance,
Carla

Comment: You may get `<form>` node and invoke `.submit` method. What is URL of the page? Please share the entire page HTML content (or relevant part).

Comment: Hi,
The relevant part can be found in the following link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QCOcNNUz8Qe7klKb3er0mT4ckhNX240V52iNJc1mfDQ/edit?usp=sharing
Please let me know if you need anything else.
Thanks in advance for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem detailed above, using the following piece of code in order to capture the action of the button:

*For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
   If ele.Type = "submit" Then ele.Click: Exit For
  Next*

Thank you all for taking a look at this publication and for every suggestion posted.

Regards,

Carla